today I am trying to build xcode (15.4) project and getting this error. Any idea how to fix it?
Anyone fix the error?
Build service could not create build operation: unable to load transferred PIF: The workspace contains multiple references with the same GUID 'PACKAGE:1XI4N5O23KKGIK69PDXW2LO4RJ58J6V2E::MAINGROUP'
update a xcode and run many time a but not solve this error.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

This question is similar to: Xcode build failed - The workspace contains multiple references with the same GUID. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Did you fix it? I have the same problem...
